# Python3 get error when constructing a map object by list constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

`list_of_input = map(float,[1,2,3])
print(list(list_of_input)[0])
print(list(list_of_input)[0])`

IndexError: list index out of range

Why does this error occur?

Comment: Could not repro the error, its working on my end

Comment: because when you generate use the function [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) this return a iterator, once this is converted to a list the [iterator](https://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#the-iteration-protocol) pull all the values, , so the next time the list_of_input is converted to a list value will be a []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversion of a map to list is done only once, meaning map is a generator object and once you transform it to list, it gets exhausted : [python 3: generator for map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644176/python-3-generator-for-map). So the error comes from second print statement and not the first.

Answer (score 0):

in Python 3 `map()` returns an iterator not a `list`. When you pass this iterator to `list` the first time it consumes the iterator so the second time you get an empty `list`, hence the IndexError.